# Troubleshooting VB6 App Crash after XP to Win7 Upgrade

Tags: debugging, windows-7, vb6, remote-debugging

I have a VB6 application that I provide support for.  This application works on both Windows XP and Windows 7.  Some users were migrated from Windows XP to Windows 7 using the User State Migration tool.  These users now receive a generic "Application has crashed" Windows error message when they open certain screens (forms) in the application.  My assumption is that there is a missing dll/ocx reference, but I'm having trouble tracking it down.

I've tried many/varied troubleshooting techniques:

- Full uninstall and reinstall of my application
- Manually re-registering all dll's and ocx's that I know are used
- Running Process Monitor on a broken computer and a working computer to compare what dll's and ocx's are accessed.  The answer might be here but even after filtering out most of the background noise the amount of data is overwhelming.  At a minimum I reviewed all of the calls right before it crashes and all of the calls that were not successful.  All of the non-successful calls match between working and non-working.
- Installed the Windows Debugger Tools and captured a crash dump.  Analyzed the crash dump with DebugDiag.  DebugDiag says the exception is in msvbvm60.dll.  I tried building a PDB file for my exe and loading it in DebugDiag to get more detail about where the exception is occuring but DebugDiag doesn't want to accept the PDB (might be doing something wrong here, but it just seems to ignore it.  This same PDB file works fine when I do remote debugging, however.)
- I recompiled my VB6 program without any optimizations in PCode.  I've read online that sometimes building in PCode, while bad for performance, will tell you the real exception.
- Used the above created PDB file to remote debug the VB6 application.  The debugger says that the application crashes after the new window has been created, on a line that sets `MousePointer = vbHourGlass`... To me it seems unlikely that this is the real cause of the error.  There are at least 20 other locations in the program where this same line is called and all work fine.
  (*Forgot about this one*)
- Used Dependency Walker and profiled the application on both a working and non-working computer.  All errors found by dependency walker were the same between the two computers.  There were no additional dependencies found on a working computer, and all missing dependencies on the non-working computer were also missing on the working one.

None of these actions changed my error message or showed me what the error is (unless it really is the mouse cursor issue)...  There are no entries in the Windows Event Log related to the app crash.

The non-working and working computers all have the same base Windows 7 image, the only difference is whatever is being changed by USMT, which further convinces me that this is some kind of quirky configuration change or a missing dll/ocx or perhaps an unregistered dll/ocx.

Any ideas or thoughts on how I can track down the root cause of the issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1 - Response to questions**
@MarkHall  I have tried running it as admin, though not with UAC off.  The application runs fine on a Windows 7 box as a non-admin with full UAC.  Windows XP was 32-bit, Windows 7 is 64-bit, but again it works just fine on a like for like box where the user was not migrated from Windows XP.

@Beaner It's possible that it stores settings somewhere that have been corrupted, but the remote debugging leads me to think that it's more likely something else since it seems to die on a step related to the UI, which then makes me think it's probably a missing dll/ocx reference.

@Bob77 The application is installed into `Program Files (x86)`.  While many of the libraries do reside in the same folder, they are all registered.

Comment: Have you tried running as administrator or with uac off? Also is your Win7 64 or 32 bit and is it different from your xp version

Comment: Does the application store and access user settings while running that could have been corrupted or otherwise migrated improperly?

Comment: Is this application fully installed into "Program Files" or are you doing something funky like dumping things into a user folder, possibly along with libraries it depends upon?  All kinds of weird things can happen if you let the VB6 runtime trigger runtime self-registration of libraries by putting them "next to" the EXE.  Aside from this I can't see where user state migration might come into the picture.

Comment: On migrated Win7 log on with a "fresh" account and try crashing the app (the crash is reproducable, isn't it). If working ok under "fresh" account probably USMT migrates some registry settings from HKCU. Bogus COM registration in HKCU?

Comment: @wqw - I've tried so many troubleshooting steps, I keep forgetting some :)  The application crashes regardless of who is logged in.  I was able to reproduce it the first time I ever logged into the box, I had never logged into it while it was an XP box.

Comment: Is it possible that one of your 3rd party controls simply does not support Windows 7?

Comment: Another step is to break out ProcMon and see what is happening in the system when you bring up the form that GPFs.

Comment: @AngryHacker - Thanks for the ideas.  First, and this can't be stressed enough, the application works just fine on x64 Windows 7.  This is not specifically a Windows 7 issue, but some kind of configuration/registration issue on specific machines. As for the second idea, I've tried using Process Monitor; there are no files that it fails to find during the time when it fails, nothing that stands out in any way between running Process Monitor on a working computer and a non-working computer and comparing the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, often I've noticed that the debugger will indicate a line of code that is actually incorrect, depending on WHERE in the actual assembly language the fault occurs.  You should look REAL close around your statement that sets the cursor to `vbHourGlass`.  Your exception is PROBABLY happening BEFORE that line of code, but that line is what the debugger thinks is the actual faulted line of code.

Since you said it happens when a window OPENS, I'd look real close at any ocx's you may have referenced on the form, but perhaps NOT actually being used, or called.  You might have one there that you don't intend to be there, that could be causing security issues, or something on Win7?  Edit the .frm file by hand if you have to, and look at all the GUIDs the form references.

It is possible that one machine is using PER-USER registration, and the other is using PER-SYSTEM registration??  I don't know...

I would take a much closer look at the form that you are trying to open, and be VERY cautious of everything you are doing in the form load events, and so on.  This sounds like it could be something as stupid as Windows Aero being enabled on one system, and not another, or some other sort of "Theme" setting that is throwing the VB Form Rendering routine into a hissyfit...  Perhaps even something as stupid as a transparent color index in the icon you selected for that from?

If you are still developing this app, (or at least maintaining it), create an entirely NEW form, and re-create all the controls, etc, on the form (resist the temptation to copy/paste them from the old one...), and then see if THAT does the trick.  Then, copy all the event code to the new form one event at a time, with at LEAST enough event code to make the form function, even if it's just a "dead form", that loads no data, or whatever the form is supposed to do.  Check and debug after each change, and you WILL find it eventually.  Of course, make sure you isolate one of the defunct systems to have a platform that you can duplicate the issue on, or then it's just guessing.  I find that using something like Acronis w/ Universal Restore is a great option to then take the image file into a good HV, like VirtualBox, and then restore that image as a VM, so you can debug without interfering with your actual users.  This sounds like a lot of work, but then again, so is re-writing an application that already exists, right?  :)

Failing THAT...  `/*` and `*/` are your friends!!  (Well, we're dealing with VB, so `'` would be your best friend!  heh...  But I'd start commenting out all the code on the form until that sucker opens.  Then once it opens, start putting one line back at a time, and re-running it...  That's called "VooDoo Debugging", but sometimes, you gotta do what you gotta do...

THANKS A LOT PETER!  :) Now you got *ME* so involved in this, I feel like **I'M** the one debugging this sucker!  Like if it was MY code I was trying to fix!  :)

Let me know if any of this helps...  I am actually quite interested in what you discover.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response, especially after all this time.  You've got some good ideas, and I'm fairly sure if I went through them all I'd find the cause.  At this point though we are retiring the application, moving to an off the shelf option instead.  I like the ideas you have though.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Sorry to hear you've moving to an off-the-shelf solution, but I guess you gotta do what you gotta do, right?  I edited my response, and added a couple more tips for anyone who might read this, to maybe help them debugging a similar situation.